# s3 error:Unable to validate the following destination configurations. Not authorized to invoke function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The Following objective I am trying to achieve. I have an s3 bucket with a  policy of cloud front and get-only policy.

```
     {
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity E*********R"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3-bucket-dev/*"
    }
]
 }
```

I was trying to add a trigger to the s3 from the Lambda function. but when I add the event notification I am getting below error.

```
Error: Unable to validate the following destination configurations. Not 
authorized to invoke the function.
```

Lambda Role has administrator access policy.